# Azure iot hub - TLS connection and x.509 authentication

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I am new to Azure IOT hub concepts,
I am trying to connect my IOT device with Azure IOT hub, by default we have TLS  support in azure iot hub, This means all communication with device will be secured by TLS.
For authenticating the device azure recommends x.509 certificates, What is the additional security this certificate brings other than authentication ? , Since the communication is already secured why we cant use symmetric keys simply, If my iot device is almost not comprisable?. Saving private key in device will be same as saving symmetric key yes?

Comment: Beyond only authentication in Azure IoT Hub, X.509 certificates offer extra security. They also enable secure key exchange, making sure that the symmetric keys needed to encrypt data between the device and the IoT hub are safely transferred and are impervious to hacking. Additionally, certificates enable secure channel setup, preventing man-in-the-middle attacks and guaranteeing that traffic between the device and the IoT hub is neither intercepted or altered.

Comment: Symmetric keys can be used to authenticate devices, although they are less secure than X.509 certificates. Symmetric keys must be managed and stored securely since they can be subject to replay, interception, and other attacks. Contrarily, X.509 certificates create confidence between the device and the user via public-key cryptography.

Comment: X.509 certificates, on the other hand, do not call for secure storage of the private key on the device and instead employ public-key cryptography to establish trust between the device and the IoT hub.

In conclusion, X.509 certificates offer further security capabilities, like secure key exchange and channel establishment, that are crucial for assuring the system's overall security, even though TLS enables safe communication between the device and the IoT hub.

Comment: Another way to think about it is that TLS means that the device can be sure that it's connecting to the correct endpoint in the cloud (as well as encrypting traffic between the device and the cloud). The X.509 cert or symmetric keys enables the device to authenticate with IoT Hub - in other words they mean the IoT hub can be sure that it's an authorized device that's connecting.

Comment: Saving a private key on a device is similar to saving a symmetric key, but [X.509](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-x509ca-overview) certificates provide an additional layer of security because the private key is protected by a password or PIN. This makes it more difficult for an attacker to [gain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-x509ca-concept) access to the private key and use it to compromise the security of the communication.

Answer (score 1):

TLS helps in providing the encryption and integrity protection for data in transit between the device and the IoT hub, which does not provide any authentication to the device.

`X.509 certificates` provide a way to authenticate the device and ensures that it is authorized to connect to the IoT hub.

`Symmetric keys authentication` is less secure than using `X.509 certificates` because the same key is used for both encryption and decryption.

And `X.509 certificates` use public key cryptography to provide a more secure method of authentication. The device has a private key that is used to sign messages, and the IoT hub has a public key that is used to verify the signature. This ensures that only authorized devices can connect to the IoT hub and that data sent from the device has not been tampered with.

Using Self signed Certificate

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "example.com" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"
```

[image]

[image]

Code to send message to IOT device with

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2("C:\\Tools\\cert\\MyCert.cer");
var auth = new DeviceAuthenticationWithX509Certificate("mydevice", cert);

var DClnt = DeviceClient.Create("HostName", auth);

var msg = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test message"));
await DClnt.SendEventAsync(msg);
```

[image]

For more information refer to the [MSDoc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-x509-test-certificate)